# Update body of Scaffold with sync from REST API

Tags: flutter

I'm having an hard time to get this working. I'm new on flutter anda have some dificult to get this working.
I already take the Future async function from controller to this file. But when I want to write nomeAluno (name of student) in the body of Scaffold, it doesn't do it. More odd, if I press Ctrl+S again, then nomeAluno appears on emulator.

If I change the code to « nomeAluno = aluno.NM_ENTIDADE_ENT + "123" » it does not reflect this change when I save. And if I restart the emulator it does not show any name, but it does show "role".

```html
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dbgep/http/aluno_http_repository.dart';
import 'package:dbgep/model/aluno_model.dart';
import 'package:dbgep/notas.dart';
import 'package:dbgep/repository/i_aluno_repository.dart';
import 'package:dbgep/welcome.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String role = "";
  String DS_LOGIN = "";
  String nomeAluno = "";
  // final IAlunoRepository _iAlunoRepository;

  // _HomePageState() : _iAlunoRepository = AlunoHttpRepository();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _lerPref();
    super.initState();
  }

  _lerPref() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(
      () {
        role = sharedPreferences.getString('role').toString();
        DS_LOGIN = sharedPreferences.getString('DS_LOGIN').toString();
        print(role);
        if (role == 'aluno') {
          _isAluno();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future _isAluno() async {
    // AlunoModel aluno = _iAlunoRepository.getAlunoAtual() as AlunoModel;
    AlunoModel aluno = await getAluno();
    nomeAluno = aluno.NM_ENTIDADE_ENT;
    print(nomeAluno);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text(
            role + ' ' + DS_LOGIN,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          Text(
            nomeAluno,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const NotasPage(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: const Text('Notas'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              bool saiu = await sair();
              if (saiu) {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const WelcomePage(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Sair'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> sair() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var url = Uri.parse('https://dbgep.gustaveeiffel-arruda.pt/api/v1/logout');
    var resposta = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'aplication/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Bearer ' + sharedPreferences.getString('token').toString(),
      },
    );
    print(sharedPreferences.getString('token').toString());
    print(resposta.statusCode);
    await sharedPreferences.clear();
    if (resposta.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<AlunoModel> getAluno() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var numero = sharedPreferences.getString('DS_LOGIN')?.substring(1);
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://dbgep.gustaveeiffel-arruda.pt/api/v1/alunos/' + numero!);
    var resposta = await http.get(
      url,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'aplication/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
            'Bearer ' + sharedPreferences.getString('token').toString(),
      },
    );
    // print(resposta.body);
    return AlunoModel.fromJson(resposta.body);
  }
}
```

I need some help, because I'm having an hard time with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setState after getting the name

```
Future _isAluno() async {
    // AlunoModel aluno = _iAlunoRepository.getAlunoAtual() as AlunoModel;
    AlunoModel aluno = await getAluno();
    nomeAluno = aluno.NM_ENTIDADE_ENT;
    print(nomeAluno);
setState((){});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the solution.

Comment: But I have another question. I know that this are "Future" functions, but "InitState" calls "_lerPref" and "_lerPref" calls "InitState" (with _isAluno)..... Does not seems to be a kind of "circular" calls? Sorry my english.

Comment: _lerPref calls setState not InitState